# Axios catch error returns JavaScript error not server response

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Im trying to catch validation errors from the server.

Code:

```
axios.post('https://myBackendIp.com/api/teacher/time/create',Data)
.then(res=>{
       console.log(res)
 }).catch(error=>{
       console.log(error)
 })
```

Console log output

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

Network tab output

```
{"error":{"message":"Check your date field","status_code":500}}
```

Is there a way to change that or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: i can't understand your question..? you are always handling async call exception right

Answer (score 5):

After Googling a little, I found this ticket:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

It recommends using:

```
console.log(error.response)
```

instead of

```
console.log(error)
```

**Edit 1:**

Did some further reading, apparently this could be a symptom of a CORS issue, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044553/axios-post-returns-network-error-even-if-status-is-200-and-theres-a-response?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error).

The request on the network tab might seem like it's succeeding, however, when it's processed by Axios, a `Network Error` is returned.

Comment: i cant get any solving methods from that tickets

Comment: Alright - what happens to your output when you use the code above?

Comment: i saw the `"undefined"` message in log when i use `console.log(error.response)`

Comment: @SanjeevanRaja - I added an additional answer above, maybe investigate that?

Comment: Yes. you are correct @n15m0-jk.
I solved my problem. its a CORS issue.
Thank you so much